# Find the vector function for two intersecting surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Find the vector function for the two intersecting surface $y=x^2$ and $10y=x^2-z^2+16$.

**My attempted solution:** I know that $x = rcos(t)$ and that $y=rsin(t)$ in this case since the intersection is an elipse shape, however I'm not really sure how to calculate $r$ without $x^2 +y^2$.

I'd be much appreciated if someone could show me how this is done. Thanks!

Comment: $y=x^2$ and $10y=x^2-z^2+16$ are not curves. They are surfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve is not a plane curve as we can see in the picture below.

From the definition
$$
\begin{cases}
y=x^2\\
10 y=x^2-z^2+16\\
\end{cases}
$$
a first parametrization is $$(t,t^2,\pm\sqrt{16-9t^2})$$
This is not nice because we should use two vectors, so we set $t=\alpha\sin u$
$$z^2=16-9t^2\to z^2=16-9 \alpha^2\sin^2 u$$
we want $9\alpha^2=16\to \alpha=\frac{4}{3}$ thus, setting
$t=\frac{4}{3}\sin u$ we get $z^2=16-16\sin^2 u\to z=4\cos u$
$$\left(\frac{4}{3}\sin u,\frac{16}{9}\sin^2 u,4\cos u \right);\;u\in[0,2\pi]$$

Hope this can help

---

[image]

Comment: Your coefficients are wrong. Setting up $x$ the way you did first seems random without an explanation of where it comes from, and second it's not going to work: $$z^2=\frac{256 \sin^2u}{81}-10\cdot\frac{256\sin^2u}{81}+16=-9\cdot\frac{256\sin^2u}{81}+16=-\frac{256\sin^2u}{9}+16=-\frac{256\sin^2u}{9}+\frac{144}{9}=\frac{144-256\sin^2u}{9},$$ and we don't get "$\frac{256\cos^2 u}{9}$" as you claim.

Comment: @Ekidona Not really. This is why I edited my answer. You should consider also $(t,t^2,-\sqrt{16-9t^2}$. To write all in a single vector I used the trig functions

Comment: @zipirovich Thank you for finding the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this ellipse is not a circle, then you are not going to have the same "$r$" in both equations.

Second, it may be easier to use such a parametrization of an ellipse for another pair of variables, not necessarily for $x$ and $y$.

Here's what I would do. Since $y=x^2$ according to the first equation, we can substitute $x^2$ for $y$ into the second equation. We'll get $10x^2=x^2-z^2+16$, which indeed is an equation of an ellipse. By simplifying this equation (move $x^2$ and $z^2$ to the left-hand side, and then divide everything by $16$), you will see how to parametrize $x=a\cos(t)$, $z=b\sin(t)$ with appropriate values of $a$ and $b$. And then the parametrization for $y$ comes from $y=x^2$.

Comment: The curve is not a plane curve. $10x^2=x^2-z^2+16$ is *on* the surface $y=x^2$, not on a plane

Comment: @Raffaele: Yes, I know. I didn't want my answer to be too long, so I admit that I sacrificed clarity and accuracy for brevity. I agree that I should've done better. This equation gives the projection of the curve of intersection onto the $xz$-plane. And it's this projection that is an ellipse and can be parametrized as I described.

Comment: @Ekidona: No, not quite. The canonical equation of an ellipse (and I'll use $x$ and $y$ for the standard cartesian plane, even though in this example it's going to be $x$ and $z$ instead) is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, and it can be parametrized as $x=a\cos(t)$, $y=b\sin(t)$. In this example, we'll get $\frac{9x^2}{16}+\frac{z^2}{16}=1$, or equivalently $\frac{x^2}{16/9}+\frac{z^2}{16}=1$. So we can see that $a^2=16/9$ and $b^2=16$.